# Cannot find -lboost_filesystem while compiling caffe

Tags: boost, makefile, caffe

I was trying to install Caffe on my Linux (Ubuntu 14.04) server without `sudo` (I am not the administrator), and when I try to make, the following error happens:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_filesystem
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Comment: Well, do you have boost installed or not?

Comment: you should build lib-boost from source if you have the recent caffe